# iphone - preventing attachments from showing

Tags: iphone

I am using MFMailComposeViewController to compose a message on a view. If I attach a PDF or an PNG, JPEG or GIF image to the message, the image is shown on the mail composition view. If the image is huge it is very difficult for the user to type the message.

Is there a way to attach a known document to a MFMailComposeViewController view and prevent the attachment from being opened? I want to be able to show the attachment as an attached file icon. I don't want to see its contents opened on the window.

Is this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot influence how `MFMailComposeViewController` displays attachments.